# how to calculate days left using PHP

Tags: php

I have two dates like this, how to calculate left days in between dates using php.

```
$date1='2016-12-26';
$date2='2017-03-21';
```

Comment: There are dozens of similar questions in SO. Initially, try yourselves from php.net manual, then check this SO forum when you face issues. Finally raise question when you are unable to.

Comment: `http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php` this will help

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to [date_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php) .Try this:

```
$d1 = new DateTime($date1);
$d2 = new DateTime($date2);

$diff = $d2->diff($d1);
echo $diff->days;  // 85
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this if **date_diff** doesn't work.Use this function if you want to get the dates between the date1 and date2 or if u want the left days between the two given dates then you can increment a number like $i below and u ca return the $i value.

```
    function date_range($date1, $date2, $step = '+1 day', $output_format = 'Y-m-d') {
      $dates = array();
      $current = strtotime($first);
      $last = strtotime($last);
      $i=1;
      while( $current <= $last ) {
        $dates[] = date($output_format, $current);
        $dateq = date($output_format, $current);
        $current = strtotime($step, $current);
        $i++;
      }        
      //return $dates; if u want the dates 
      return $i; //if u want the count of dates between the tow given dates
    }
```

Hope this help you..